# Going from Mean Residual Life function to Survival Function

Tags: survival

I know its connected through the Cumulative Hazard Function but can't seem to get there

I'm trying to go from $m(t)=\frac{\int_{t}^{\infty}S(u)du}{S(t)}$ to $S(t)=\frac{m(0)}{m(t)}exp\{-\int_{0}^{t}m(u)^{-1}du\}$.